# Help me verify this simple claim about continuous function on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Proposition: Let $y$ be a fixed number in $\mathbb{R}$, given $f$ continuous and suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all
> $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 0$ only when $x = y$, then there
> exists some $k > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq k$ for all $x \neq y$.

I think this is a trivial consequence of continuous function on the real line. Maybe directly from the epsilon-delta definition.  But I cannot remember exactly what the sequence of arguments are, or perhaps a theorem that can show this. I'm also concerned about $\geq$ vs $>$ in the latter half of the statement, but it seems to be intuitive also.  Can someone verify the proposition and provide a line of reasoning.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but it seems to me that $f(x) = |x|$ with $y=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In fact it is wrong for all continuous functions: if $f(x) \ge k > 0$ for all $x \ne y$  then $f(y) \ge k > 0$.

Comment: "suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}.$ " Doesn't make sense, $y$ is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is true.

Consider

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto |x|$$

Let $y = 0$. Then $f(x) \geq 0$ and $f(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$. But there can't exist $k>0$ such that $f(x) \geq k$ for all $x$, since $f(\frac{k}{2}) = \frac{k}{2} < k$ for any $k>0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. $f(x)=x^2$ only vanishes at $0$ but can be arbitrarily small for $x \neq 0$.